# Android Studio - ¿Como paso datos desde un fragment hacia una actividad con "interface"?

Tags: android, android-studio, interface, drawerlayout

**Descripción**

Tengo una app la cual tiene un navigation drawer, es decir que tengo una actividad la cual cambia de fragments según los items que se seleccionen de este drawer. El tema es que en el primer ítem (primer fragment) hay un botón el cual quiero que al ser tocado abra el drawer. Como el drawer está en la actividad y no en el fragment, se debería pasar un dato **desde** el fragment **hacia** la actividad el cual indique que se abra el drawer.

**Que intenté?**

Probé reabriendo la actividad desde el fragment con Intent, y aproveché esta llamada para usar un **putExtra**. El problema es que la actividad se re-abre y yo solamente quiero que se abra el drawer.

**En resumen:**

Quiero tocar el botón desde mi fragment, que llegue un dato a la actividad que indique que se abra el drawer, y que este se abra.

Creo que para esto sería adecuado usar **interface** las cuales estuve investigando pero ninguna respuesta me fue útil. Agradecería su ayuda!

**Código Java de mi fragment:**

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("drawer_open","yes");
            startActivity(intent);
```

**Código Java de mi actividad:**

```
String drawer_open = datos_filtros.getString("drawer_open");
if(drawer_open != null){
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ocultarTeclado();
                }
            },200);
        }
```

**Gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 1):

tratare de explicar:

Esto es un ejemplo de como pasar un texto desde un fragment a un activity, basicamente tengo

- MainActivity
- MainFragment
- MainListener

Este es mi Activity, lo importante aqui es `implements MainListener` y en metodo `receiveData`

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainListener {

    private TextView tvData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvData = findViewById(R.id.tvData);
        callFragment(new MainFragment());
    }
    @Override
    public void receiveData(String data) {
        if (data != null) {
            tvData.setText(data);
        }
     }

    private void callFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

A continuacion el Listener, solo tiene `receiveData` y recibe como parametro un String

```
public interface MainListener {
    // Este metodo se sobre escribe en el activity 
    void receiveData(String data);
}
```

Luego viene el Fragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private MainListener listener; 

public MainFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Button btnSendData = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendData);

    btnSendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.sendData("esto es lo que se envia"); //aqui hago uso del listener
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    listener = (MainListener) context; // crea una instancia del listener
    }
}
```

En el fragment debes llamar al listener de forma privada `private MainListener listener` pero antes de usarlo debes crear una instancia de el, eso lo haces en el metodo `onAttach`
la forma de instanciar una interfaz puede variar.

El fragment tiene un boton, y lo que hace es que cuando lo presionas envia el String "**esto es lo que se envia**".

Eso es todo lo que se necesita para enviar un dato desde un fragment hacia un activity, espero que sea de ayuda, comentame si hay algo que no se entienda.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!